# Gmail app is crashing when i attach a image through emailIntent Android

Tags: android, android-intent

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Image Attachment");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(resize_file));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));


private void compress(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1024, 800, false);
    try {
        resize_file = createTemporaryFile("resize", ".jpg");
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream fOut;
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(resize_file);
        out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        bitmap.recycle();
        out.recycle();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Gmail Trace:
[image: Gamil crash]

Gmail app opens with the attached file, but as soon when i click on send button, i'm getting an error message 'Gmail app is not responding'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be something wrong with your 'resize_file' image file

Comment: I have added the resize_file method also plz check @AHoneyBustard

Comment: Not sure but seems like with 'out.recycle();' you are recycling your created compressed bitmap before doing anything with it.

Comment: Got it? If not the error is probably in this method : createTemporaryFile("resize", ".jpg")

Comment: No, that is not the problem, i tried even change the other way but same result.@AHoneyBustard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what was the proper issue. But Clearing Gmail app data, fixed my issue. Any way thanks to A Honey Bustard for his reply..